# C - split string into an array of strings

Tags: c, c-strings

I'm not completely sure how to do this in C:

```
char* curToken = strtok(string, ";");
//curToken = "ls -l" we will say
//I need a array of strings containing "ls", "-l", and NULL for execvp()
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you want to split based on spaces, why have you specified `;` as the delimiter?

Comment: For example: string = "ls -l; date; set +v"

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Since you've already looked into `strtok` just continue down the same path and split your string using space (`' '`) as a delimiter, then use something as `realloc` to increase the size of the array containing the elements to be passed to `execvp`.

See the below example, but keep in mind that `strtok` will modify the string passed to it. If you don't want this to happen you are required to make a copy of the original string, using `strcpy` or similar function.

```
char    str[]= "ls -l";
char ** res  = NULL;
char *  p    = strtok (str, " ");
int n_spaces = 0, i;


/* split string and append tokens to 'res' */

while (p) {
  res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * ++n_spaces);

  if (res == NULL)
    exit (-1); /* memory allocation failed */

  res[n_spaces-1] = p;

  p = strtok (NULL, " ");
}

/* realloc one extra element for the last NULL */

res = realloc (res, sizeof (char*) * (n_spaces+1));
res[n_spaces] = 0;

/* print the result */

for (i = 0; i < (n_spaces+1); ++i)
  printf ("res[%d] = %s\n", i, res[i]);

/* free the memory allocated */

free (res);
```

```
res[0] = ls
res[1] = -l
res[2] = (null)
```

Comment: @JordanCarney glad to be of service.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp Can you explain the last code block before the printing and freeing the memory, the: `/* realloc one extra element for the last NULL */`? I'm having difficulty understanding it

Comment: @Abdul I believe usually there is a null character at the end of each array so that the computer can differentiate between two different arrays.

Comment: if I wrap this into a function and return the `res` pointer, I get a warning after freeing the pointer I assigned `res` to, saying: `warning: attempt to free a non-heap object [-Wfree-nonheap-object]`. Do you have any insight of the cause?

Answer (score 6):

[Here is an example of how to use strtok](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8d19sb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) borrowed from MSDN.

And the relevant bits, you need to call it multiple times.  The `token` char* is the part you would stuff into an array (you can figure that part out).

```
char string[] = "A string\tof ,,tokens\nand some  more tokens";
char seps[]   = " ,\t\n";
char *token;

int main( void )
{
    printf( "Tokens:\n" );
    /* Establish string and get the first token: */
    token = strtok( string, seps );
    while( token != NULL )
    {
        /* While there are tokens in "string" */
        printf( " %s\n", token );
        /* Get next token: */
        token = strtok( NULL, seps );
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this much, but this does not give me an array of strings from the tokens. I guess I don't understand that specific part of it.

Comment: Why `token = strtok(NULL, seps);`? Why the `NULL`?

Comment: @c650 See the linked page from MSDN, subsequent calls need the `NULL`.

Comment: Ah yes I did much Googling and have found out that `strtok()` uses a static variable to save its place.