# Put each word of a string into array in C

Tags: c, arrays, strtok

I'm trying to split up a string (typed in by the user at run time) into words (separated by spaces), and put each word into a different slot into an array. So, for example, if I took the string `"hello world"`, `array[0]` would contain `"hello"` and `array[1]` would contain `"world"`. And the last slot (in this case `array[2]`) would contain `NULL`. Here's what I have so far, which doesn't seem to be working properly. Any help would be appreciated. (By the way, this is part of a program which will call `execvp(argv[0],argv);` )

```
char input[100];
char* argv[20];
char* token;
scanf("%s", input);

//get the first token
token = strtok(input, " ");

int i=0;
//walk through other tokens
while( token != NULL ) {
    argv[i] = token;
    i++;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    } 
argv[i] = NULL; //argv ends with NULL
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - split string into an array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198604/c-split-string-into-an-array-of-strings)

Comment: You have to deal with couple of issues: reading the user data and splitting up the user data into tokens. Using `"%s"` format in `scanf` in a loop should adequately address both.

Comment: Can you explain what "isn't working properly" means here? Your loop is walking through the input character array, overwriting each space it finds with `'\0'`, and saving pointers to the beginning of each token. That sounds like what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just figured out my problem: I need to use gets() instead of scanf(), because scanf() only gets the first word, up until a space, while I want to be able to get a string containing multiple words  separated by spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate memory for each argv[i] and copy the current token to argv[i]:

```
token = strtok(input, " ");

int i=0;
//walk through other tokens
while( token != NULL ) {
    argv[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
    strncpy(argv[i], token, strlen(token));
    //argv[i] = token;
    i++;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    } 
argv[i] = NULL; //argv ends with NULL
```

Comment: No, you don't need to allocate space, just for the pointers.  `strtok(3)` walks through the original string putting `\0`'s at the first `char` encountered in the string, belonging also to the second string parameter to `strtok(3)`.  you can use the original string `input` or a `dup(3)`'ed one, if you want to conserve/save `malloc()`'s.  Also, in your example, you can call `strdup(3)` which does both, the malloc and the `strcpy(3)` for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example of what I think you want.  I have used one `malloc(3)` for the whole
line of strings and another for the array of pointers you will get from the function.

Also, the second parameter of `strtok(3)` is passed to give more flexibility (the shell normally uses the contents of IFS environment variable to separate arguments so you can use the same algorithm as the shell does)  I think you should use `" \n\t"` at least.  It has a `main()` test function, so it's complete for your purpose.

```
#include <assert.h> /* man assert(3) */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc lives here */
#include <string.h> /* strtok, strdup lives here */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf lives here */

char **split(const char *str, const char *delim)
{
    char *aux;
    char *p;
    char **res;
    char *argv[200]; /* place for 200 words. */
    int n = 0, i;

    assert(aux = strdup(str));
    for (p = strtok(aux, delim); p; p = strtok(NULL, delim))
        argv[n++] = p;
    argv[n++] = NULL;
    /* i'll put de strdup()ed string one place past the NULL,
     * so you can free(3), once finished */
    argv[n++] = aux;
    /* now, we need to copy the array, so we can use it outside
     * this function. */
    assert(res = calloc(n, sizeof (char *)));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        res[i] = argv[i];
    return res;
} /* split */

int main()
{
    char **argv =
        split("Put each word of a string into array in C", " ");
    int i;

    for (i = 0; argv[i]; i++)
        printf("[%s]", argv[i]);
    puts("");  /* to end with a newline */

    free(argv[i+1]);
    free(argv);
} /* main */
```

The sample code just outputs:

```
$ pru
[Put][each][word][of][a][string][into][array][in][C]
```