# How do I create a function in C that allows me to split a string based on a delimiter into an array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, realloc

I want to create a function in C, so that I can pass the function a string, and a delimiter, and it will return to me an array with the parts of the string split up based on the delimiter. Commonly used to separate a sentence into words.

e.g.: `"hello world foo"` -> `["hello", "world", "foo"]`

However, I'm new to C and a lot of the pointer things are confusing me. I got an answer mostly from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198604/c-split-string-into-an-array-of-strings), but it does it inline, so when I try to separate it into a function the logistics of the pointers are confusing me:

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void split_string(char string[], char *delimiter, char ***result) {
    char *p = strtok(string, delimiter);
    int i, num_spaces = 0;

    while (p != NULL) {
        num_spaces++;
        &result = realloc(&result, sizeof(char *) * num_spaces);

        if (&result == NULL) {
            printf("Memory reallocation failed.");
            exit(-1);
        }

        &result[num_spaces - 1] = p;

        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    // Add the null pointer to the end of our array
    &result = realloc(split_array, sizeof(char *) * num_spaces + 1);
    &result[num_spaces] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < num_spaces; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", &result[i]);
    }

    free(&result);
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char str[] = "hello world 1 foo";
    char **split_array = NULL;

    split_string(str, " ", &split_array);

    return 0;
}
```

The gist of it being that I have a function that accepts a string, accepts a delimiter and accepts a pointer to where to save the result. Then it constructs the result. The variable for the result starts out as NULL and without memory, but I gradually reallocate memory for it as needed.

But I'm really confused as to the pointers, like I said. I know my result is of type `char **` as a string it of type `char *` and there are many of them so you need pointers to each, but then I'm supposed to pass the *location* of that `char **` to the new function, right, so it becomes a `char ***`? When I try to access it with `&` though it doesn't seem to like it.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here, I'd really appreciate insight into what is going wrong with the code.

Comment: `&result = ...` stop right there. that isn't an lvalue.

Comment: `&result` would be of type `char ****` inside `split_string`. You need to de-reference it. Maybe with `*result` instead ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confusing dereferencing with *addressing* (which is the complete opposite). Btw, I couldn't find `split_array` anywhere in the function, as it was down in `main`. Even if you had the dereferencing and addressing correct, this would still have other issues.

I'm fairly sure you're trying to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void split_string(char string[], const char *delimiter, char ***result)
{
    char *p = strtok(string, delimiter);
    void *tmp = NULL;
    int count=0;

    *result = NULL;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        tmp = realloc(*result, (count+1)*sizeof **result);
        if (tmp)
        {
            *result = tmp;
            (*result)[count++] = p;
        }
        else
        {   // failed to expand
            perror("Failed to expand result array");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        p = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }

    // add null pointer
    tmp = realloc(*result, (count+1)*sizeof(**result));
    if (tmp)
    {
        *result = tmp;
        (*result)[count] = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Failed to expand result array");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "hello world 1 foo", **toks = NULL;
    char **it;

    split_string(str, " ", &toks);

    for (it = toks; *it; ++it)
        printf("%s\n", *it);
    free(toks);
}
```

**Output**

```
hello
world
1
foo
```

Honestly this would be cleaner if the function result were utilized rather than an in/out parameter, but you choice the latter, so there you go.

Best of luck.