# C - Split string into an array of strings at certain characters

Tags: arrays, string, char

I have this string: `"apples,cakes,cupcakes,bannanas"`

How can I **efficiently** break this up into an array like the following?

```
["apples"]["cakes"]["cupcakes"]["bannanas"]
```

There seem to be a lot of answers for c++ out there but I am struggling to find a answer for C. All i want to do is split this into a array at every `','`. Any suggestions??

Comment: The easy way is [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) on an input stream. Read up on [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) for a quick way to turn a string into an input stream.

Comment: I thought std was a c++ library. Sorry, I am new to c and c++.

Comment: You tagged the question with C++, I gave a C++ answer. If you need to restrict your answers to C, edit your question and replace the C++ tag with the C tag. You will probably get a better quality of response.

Comment: Sorry im coding with c++ but using c strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use strtok()?

string str as apples,cakes,cupcakes,bannanas and delim ",".

```
char *token;
token = strtok(str, delim);
while(token != NULL)
{
       printf("%s\n", token);
       token = strtok(NULL,delim);
 }
```

may this help.

Comment: How does this return an array on strings??? I need a array with each split string in it.

Comment: Replace the print line with a strcpy of the `char` array into the string array. Or better still, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Thanks!! I just pushed the token into a vector :D

Comment: Two things to watch out for: 1. `strtok` destroys your source string. This is OK if you aren't using the string again and you aren't using it on a constant string with the assistance of a cast. 2. If you place the `char *` returned from `strtok` into the `std::vector` without copying the string at the `char *` into a `char` array in the `std::vector`, the `std::vector` relies on the continued existence of the tokenized string. If this string goes out of scope, all the pointers in the `std::vector` will refer to garbage and further use will result in unpredictable and undefined behaviour.

Comment: Too late to edit my previous comment. "strtok destroys your source string." is really bad wording. The string isn't destroyed in the destructor sense. The contents are changed. In this case every time strtok encounters a `','`, the `','` is replaced with a null. Attempts to read from the source string will terminate at the end of the first token because it is now null terminated.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

You can use strtok function
See [documentation for strtok here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)

Similar question was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198604/c-split-string-into-an-array-of-strings)