# fork() and exec(): parameter with space

Tags: c, escaping, exec

I want to fork and exec a binary in c. The parameter for calling the binary contains a space, see first line of sample code. If execute my binary with `plist [2] = conPtr -> conmon_cmd[f];` the parameter is not evaluated correctly.

Using the two commented line will bring me the result which I desire. How can I escape the space in the first line of the code snippet so that I have only **one** plist parameter for the arguments?

```
conPtr->conmon_cmd = "clear_config all";
[...]
printf("child process started (PID = %i)\n", pid);  
char *plist[6];
plist [0] = "/tmp/conmon_audinate_controller";
plist [1] = "localhost";
plist [2] = conPtr -> conmon_cmd;
//plist [2] = "clear_config";
//plist [3] = "all";
plist [4] = (char *)NULL;
char *file = "conmon_audinate_controller";
execvp (file,  plist );
```

Info: the conmon_audinate_controller is an external executable. In the bash on my ucLinux the call would be like:
`/tmp # ./conmon_audinate_controller localhost clear_config all`

Comment: What is the variable `f`?

Comment: sry f should not have been there, I removed it

Comment: What is `/tmp/conmon_audinate_controller`?  Is it a script of some sort that parses arguments? A binary executable?  You need to post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or the only answers you get are going to be guesses.

Comment: `Using the two commented line will bring me the result which I desire` if that fix your problem why don't your go ahead with that? Do you face any issue because of that?

Comment: because the parameters do not always have a structure like that. Anyway I changed my code so that it doesn't matter if one or more parameters are forwarded.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have a single C-string (with two words) that you want to pass as *two* arguments to `conmon_audinate_controller`.

`exec` family functions don't support such thing - "clear_config all" will be passed as a single argument. What you can do is split `conPtr->conmon_cmd`, [using `strtok` for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11198604/1275169), into two and pass two arguments (like the commented out lines).

Comment: Ok this is not what I wanted to hear but if it's so I need to change my approach. Thanks